# How to easily create event handler method?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Subscribing to event is easy: type `+=`, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

[image]

But is there an easy way to create event handler method when there is no `+=` ? To example when event is a method parameters:

[image]

My current approach is very inefficient:

- Look at method signature (using <kbd>F12</kbd> - go to definition);
- Copy type of `EventHandler<T>`;
- manually type and paste to create event handler: `void foo(object sender,`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> `args)`.

Do I miss something? Is there a quicker way to create `foo`?

P.S.: I am talking about event handlers, but this question may be extended to creating delegate callbacks too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the name of the method that you want to generate (as if it already existed), then put your cursor over the name and press `Ctrl+.`, and select "Generate method ...":

[image: Screenshot showing refactoring to "Generate method"]

`EventHandler` and `EventHandler<T>` are just a types of delegate -- they're no different to e.g. `Func` or `Action`, other than the way in which they're normally used.